# jQuery next DIV with Specific Class that resides in another DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

To make the question short, here is the HTML code that I have:

```
<div class="step1 main-step">
    <div class="step1a tooltip" step-name="step1a" title="Step 1a" style="width: 25.000%;"></div>
    <div class="step1b tooltip" step-name="step1b" title="Step 1b" style="width: 25.000%;"></div>
    <div class="step1c tooltip" step-name="step1c" title="Step 1c" style="width: 25.000%;"></div>               
    <div class="step1d tooltip" step-name="step1d" title="Step 1d" style="width: 25.000%;"></div>
</div> <!-- End of Step 1 -->

<div class="step2 main-step">
    <div class="step2a tooltip" step-name="step2a" title="Step 2a" style="width: 25.000%;"></div>            
    <div class="step2b tooltip" step-name="step2b" title="Step 2b" style="width: 25.000%;"></div>
    <div class="step2c tooltip" step-name="step2c" title="Step 2c" style="width: 25.000%;"></div>
    <div class="step2d tooltip" step-name="step2d" title="Step 2d" style="width: 25.000%;"></div>
</div> <!-- End of Step 2 -->

<a href="#" current-step="step1a" next-step="step1b" class="button" id="continue-button">Continue</a>
```

Now, my problem is when I use this jQuery code:

```
$nextStep = $('#continue-button').attr('next-step');    
$('#continue-button').attr('current-step', $nextStep);
$nextTemp = $('div.' + $nextStep).next('.tooltip').attr('step-name');
$('#continue-button').attr('next-step', $nextTemp);
```

*$nextTemp* stops at *step1d*. What can I do so $nextTemp will read the next div.tooltip from the other divs (step2, step3, step4, etc.) ?

Comment: How you are getting `$nextStep`

Comment: It looks like you are overcomplicating it. Why don't you use a common class and then iterate through matched set to get next one? BTW, don't use invalid HTML attributes, use `data-*` instead

Comment: $nextStep = $('#continue-button').attr('next-step');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

External **[Fiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/mg4jLewL/4/)**

Well I have made some changes to your `html` to use a valid `html data-* attributes` which will be as follows and also check for inline comments:

```js
$(".button").on('click',function(){
    var currentStep=$(this).data('current-step'); //get the current-step
    var $nextStep=$('.'+currentStep).next('.tooltip').length?$('.'+currentStep).next('.tooltip').data('step-name'):$('.'+currentStep).closest('.main-step').next('.main-step').find('div:first').data('step-name');
    //ternary operator if there is nextstep in current main-step then take it otherwise
    //go to its parent and get next main-step first div's step-name data attribute
    if(typeof $nextStep !=  'undefined') //check if it is undefined
    {
     $(this).data('current-step', $nextStep);
 $nextTemp = $('div.' + $nextStep).next().length?$('div.' + $nextStep).next().data('step-name'):$('.'+$nextStep).closest('.main-step').next().find('div:first').data('step-name');
 typeof $nextTemp!='undefined'?$(this).data('next-step', $nextTemp):$(this).data('next-step', 'No more steps');
        //ternary operators again
    }
    $('.result').append("Current Step : " +$(this).data('current-step')+ " " + "Next Step :" +$(this).data('next-step') +"<br/>");
    //just to show what the results will be after each click.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="step1 main-step">
    <div class="step1a tooltip" data-step-name="step1a" title="Step 1a" style="width: 25.000%;"></div>
    <div class="step1b tooltip" data-step-name="step1b" title="Step 1b" style="width: 25.000%;"></div>
    <div class="step1c tooltip" data-step-name="step1c" title="Step 1c" style="width: 25.000%;"></div>               
    <div class="step1d tooltip" data-step-name="step1d" title="Step 1d" style="width: 25.000%;"></div>
</div> <!-- End of Step 1 -->

<div class="step2 main-step">
    <div class="step2a tooltip" data-step-name="step2a" title="Step 2a" style="width: 25.000%;"></div>            
    <div class="step2b tooltip" data-step-name="step2b" title="Step 2b" style="width: 25.000%;"></div>
    <div class="step2c tooltip" data-step-name="step2c" title="Step 2c" style="width: 25.000%;"></div>
    <div class="step2d tooltip" data-step-name="step2d" title="Step 2d" style="width: 25.000%;"></div>
</div> <!-- End of Step 2 -->

<a href="#" data-current-step="step1a" data-next-step="step1b" class="button" id="continue-button">Continue</a>

<div class='result'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved cycling the divs, instead of trying to get it directly

```
$( "#continue-button" ).click( function() {
    $nextStep = $('#continue-button').attr('next-step');    
    $('#continue-button').attr('current-step', $nextStep);

    var foundDiv = false;
    $( ".tooltip" ).each( function() {
        if( foundDiv ) {
            $nextTemp = $( this ).attr( "step-name" );
            foundDiv = false;
        } else {
            if( $( this ).attr( "step-name" ) == $nextStep ) {
                foundDiv = true;
            }
        }
    });
    $('#continue-button').attr('next-step', $nextTemp);
});
```